# Why is AC current attractive and DC repulsive?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-fields, electric-current

I want to know whether alternating current will hold you to stick to the socket or throw you away and why?
In my textbook it is written that alternating current is attractive in nature but when i researched a bit i found that it will contract your muscles and make you stick to the socket.
So i want to know which of the fact is correct and why?
Please i want a complete explanation as I am totally confused.

Comment: What do you mean by attractive? I'm with the impression that there is a huge misunderstanding here. Please try to include more context on where you read that AC is attractive. What was the text about? Are you sure it was just not saying for example "AC is a more attractive [technology] than DC for power grid distribution". Secondly, you state that AC is "attractive" and that it also makes you "stick to the socket", so I see that being in line with each other, not against.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be referring to something like a person holding and unable to release an object they are grasping that becomes electrically live.

In electric shock parlance this is sometimes referred to as "muscle freezing"  or "muscle tetanus". It is due to current passing through the body, not because of any "attraction" effect. The physiological response is most pronounced for AC current.

At lower levels of current  a person may experience a "startle reaction" in which they are able to release the live object.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Electric current (both AC and DC) has no attractive or repultive power. Nerves and muscles in the human body work on electrical current in the form of ion-transfer (because ions are charged particles), however, this flow is very small. When high current is passed through your body, your nerves and muscles are affected...
If your feet are in contact with the ground and you TOUCH a nacked wire with high voltage, electric current starts flowing through your body. This current will impair the functioning of your nerves and muscles. But, as soon as the current starts flowing through the body, you get a jerk (shock) due to a reflex action (It's like Pulling our hands away immediately after touching a hot or cold object,,, or if you are doing something and your friend pricks your hand with a needle without your knowledge, then you immediately pull your hand away).

But, if you HOLD the wire instead of touching it, you can't release the wire because the muscles in your hand won't work properly. You will get continuous jerks due to reflex action but you will not be able to open your hand. Eventually, it looks like you are stuck to the wire.

Please note that the answer gives very basic information for easy understanding. Please never TOUCH any live-wire without prior knowledge of the potential risks, as even a large amount of electrical current flowing over a very short period of time can be life threatening.

In this answer, I tried to explain the basics of electric shock in case of current flowing in the direction from hand to foot (considering not affecting the heart and brain). There can be more complicated and more dangerous conditions in real life situations.

Comment: Welcome! I've converted some things that looked like paragraph breaks in your raw text into blank lines, so they show up as paragraphs in the displayed answer. I've also removed a personal introduction. Personal descriptions should go in your user profile page, which you can find (and edit) by clicking on your username. To see the original version of your answer, clicked the "edited X ago" link at the bottom; you can also add [edit]s of your own.